# Integrated Gradient on question classification

Tags: gradient, integrated

I'm trying to implement the Integrated gradient on question classification (https://github.com/ankurtaly/Integrated-Gradients). The problem is that I don't get how to compute the gradient of the predictions. Does anyone have some hint? Thank you

Comment: * i'm using gradient tape

Comment: Hi, and welcome to s-o. I am afraid your question is not very clear - perhaps following https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help?